# Run setState when 2 states are the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do a 4 digit auth using this [react-input-code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-code-input)

On input change, I am setting the state: usesrAuth and I have another static state: code. I am trying to achieve when these two states matched, I want to set another state: isAuthenticated to true. What happens is, when state changes and these two states are the same, isAuthenticated state doesn't change. Can you help me how I can check for 2  states is truthy and update the 3rd state?

```
state = {
    userAuth: '',
    code: '1234',
    cart: [],
    currentItem: { 
        text: '',
        key: ''
    },
    isAuthenticated: false
}
```

On change from react-input-code component will update the userAuth state.

```
<ReactCodeInput
    type='number'
    fields={4}
    onChange={ this.props.authInput } 
/>

// props passed function
handleAuthInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        userAuth: e
    })
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is this when this.state.userAuth === this.state.code. I want to set the state isAuthenticated: true which will then show/hide some HTML depending on this isAuthenticated state.

```
state = {
  userAuth: '1234',
  code: '1234',
  isAuthenticated: false
}
```

Let me know how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update your state you can check if the new `userAuth` and `code` match and set `isAuthenticated` to `true` if that's the case.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    userAuth: "1234",
    code: "",
    isAuthenticated: false
  };

  onChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const state = { ...prevState, [name]: value };
      state.isAuthenticated = state.userAuth === state.code;
      return state;
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { userAuth, code, isAuthenticated } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input name="userAuth" value={userAuth} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <input name="code" value={code} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <div>{isAuthenticated ? "Match!" : "No match"}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```